# Design review: how well does my object oriented design fit the SOLID principles?

Tags: design, architecture, object-oriented-design, review

*This thread will be long, but I will try to make it as short as I can. Thank you.*

I have recently implemented a relatively simple program. What this program does is generate a simple piece of music and play it.

I will describe the object oriented design of the program and would like to hear your review of the design. **Especially how well it fits the SOLID principles**, where it doesn't, and how I can improve my design to be more SOLID in the future.

*(If there's something in the description that isn't clear enough, please tell me.)*

I have divided my design into two parts.

**1-** The "behind the scenes" system that generates the content - a series of notes and chords (as will be explained later) - and is responsible for playing it.

**2-** The system that provides a UI to control the "behind the scenes" system. This system tells the other system when to create new music and when to play it.

I will describe each system separately.

---

**System 1 - responsible for the generating and playing music.**

The way music is created is by first generating a chord progression (a series of chords to be played one after the other), and then generating a melody based on that progression. I will describe how this is designed 'from the bottom up'.

**Generating a chord progression**.

Class `Note`: the most basic class. Responsible for playing sound files, and is set in instantiation to play a specific sound (C, D, etc.). It has an interface to play() and to stop() the playback. It also has a method `getName()` to identify it (the name is fed to the Note through the constructor).

Class `Chord`: this class is instantiated with an array of three `Note` objects and a name. For example, a `Chord` named `cMajor` will be instantiated with the Notes `c`, `e`, and `g` and the string "CMajor". `Chord` has an interface to play() and stop() the notes it's composed with, has a method `getName()` and a method `getNotes()` that returns the array of Notes.

Class `Progression`: this class is instantiated with an array of `Chord` objects, and has logic to play and stop them one after the other in a particular tempo (speed, in BPM - beats per minute). It has a method `play(int bpm)` and a method `getChords()` that returns the array of Chords.

Class `ProgressionGenerator`: implements an algorithm to create a particular series of `Chord` objects, and instantiate a `Progression` with these chords.

To summarize: a Progression is composed of Chords, which are composed of Notes. The ProgressionGenerator instantiates a Progression with a particular series of Chords.

**Generating a melody**.

Class `MelodyNote`: composed with a single `Note`. It has an attribute `double duration` which specifies for how long this note is to be played relative to a measure/bar of music (e.g. 'half note' is specified as 0.5, 'quarter' as 0.25). It has a method `getDuration()` and an interface to play() and stop() it's inner `Note` (basically delegates to the Note).

Class `Melody`: composed with a series of `MelodyNote`s. Has logic to play the series of notes in a particular speed. It uses each `MelodyNote`'s `duration` to know when to stop a note and play the next one.

Class `MelodyGenerator`: implements an algorithm to generate a series of `MelodyNote`s and instantiate a `Melody` with it. It does this based on a `Progression`. The method signature is `Melody generate(Progression prog)`.

**So to summarize:**

Progression **--> composed with** Chords **--> composed with** Notes

Melody **--> composed with** MelodyNote

**Each object controls it's inner objects and exposes them.** For example Chord has logic to play it's inner Notes, and has a method `getNotes()` that returns them to whoever needs to know. For example, `MelodyGenerator` uses `progression.getChords()` in order to build a melody according a particular series of chords. It also uses `chord.getNotes()` when choosing what notes to place over a chord.

**One last thing:** the generators use the singleton class `NotesAndChordsSupplier` to get the Note and Chord instances they need. It hands them existing instances.

---

**System 2 - responsible for providing a UI to control the creation and playback of music.**

This system is designed using the **MVC pattern.** The Model encapsulates the creation and playing of music. The View is the UI that provides buttons to tell the Model to play and make new music. The Controller is notified by the View when buttons are pressed and invokes the proper actions on the Model.

**The Model**

The Model contains a `Progression`, a `ProgressionGenerator`, a `Melody` and a `MelodyGenerator`. When it's told to generate new music, it simply delegates the task to the generators. When it's told to play music, it delegates the task to the melody and progression. Simplified code:

```
public void makeNewMusic(){
    progression = progGenerator.generate();
    melody = melodyGenerator.generate(progression);
}

public void playMusic(){ // this actually starts two separate threads, but irrelevant.
    progression.play();
    melody.play();
}
```

The Model is connected (in a loosely-coupled manner) to two objects: it's `Melody` and the `View` - both via the Observer pattern.

The Model implements two interfaces: `Observer` and `Observable`. It's registered as an observer to the Melody, and the View is registered as an Observer to the Model.

When the Melody finishes it's playback, it notifies it's observer - the Model. When the Model is notified, it notifies it's own observer - the View.

This way, the View gets notifies when playback is finished, so it can re-enable it's UI buttons that were disabled during playback.

**The View**

The View is the UI and it has two buttons: `Play` and `New Tune`. They invoke `playButtonPressed()` and `newTuneButtonPressed()` on the Controller, respectively.

The View also features `enableButtons()` and `disableButtons()` methods.

As I said, the View is registered as an Observer to the Model. It is notified when playback of the music is finished, so it can re-enable it's buttons that were disabled by the Controller when playback started.

**The Controller**

When the View calls `newTuneButtonPressed()` on the Controller, it simply delegates to the Model: `model.makeNewMusic()`.

When the View invokes `playButtonPreesed()` on the Controller, two things happen. 1- The Controller calls `disableButtons()` on the View. 2- The Controller calls `playMusic()` on the Model.

All buttons on the View are disabled by the Controller when music playback starts.

The Controller registers the View as an observer to the Model, and the Model as an observer to it's member Melody.

---

**UML class diagram to illustrate the architecture**

*(Please note: in this post I ommited a class `Scale`, which isn't important. Ignore it in the diagram).*

[image]

---

**Thank you for reading all of this. I will appreciate any kind of criticism of the object oriented design of the program.**

**Especially, how well are SOLID and OO principles integrated in my design, and how can I design more in the spirit of SOLID on the future.**

Comment: I've removed your link to the full size picture, which Websense identified as "adult/swimwear apparel."  If anyone wants to see the full size graphic, they can just right-click the picture and open it in a new tab or window.

Comment: This should go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @IdanArye: Code Review only accepts code from functioning programs for review, not designs.

Comment: Be careful about embedding the names into your objects.  Identical notes have different names depending on the key.  You can instead use a number that can be used to identify the octave and the note (The MIDI value can be good for this).

Comment: Surely you are missing an instrument for playing melodies. Note shouldn't be playing itself.

Comment: @CodeART My goal when designing this was to create a pretty simple program, that generates melodies and plays them. I wasn't aiming for diversity in sound, because I wasn't even sure I could accomplish this relatively simple task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I can give you a thorough review via internet, but some notes as I read through:

- There is more than one note with the same name. Low C, middle C, high C, etc. And even there, "high"/"low" is relative to the instrument playing them, so those probably aren't sufficient names.
- I don't particularly like `Note` knowing how to play itself. The same note can be played by different instruments, for different durations, with different techniques (trill, staccato, etc.).
- I don't particularly like having a `play` **and** `stop`. This adds temporal coupling (you can only stop after play. Play with a duration may be better.
- I don't particularly like `Note` being constructable. There is a well defined set of notes. Making them static and immutable makes them more easily comparable, better in concurrent scenarios, easier to reason about...
- You don't mention the language, but `getBlah` methods are smelly to me.
- `Progression` has a beats per minute, but that assumes each chord gets equal time. It also assumes that there's no transition between chords/notes (slurs, percussion effects).
- There's no reason to have a singleton. Even if you don't want the notes and stuff to be static & immutable, having more than one flyweight isn't going to end the world. If you only want one, only make one.
- As a matter of practicality, you will likely need to test playing the notes in sequence (if that is what you plan to do) since program (and sound card) latency may make it sound bad.
- I am not sure your generators are sufficiently generic enough to include directly in the model. You should consider having interfaces for those dependencies.
- Your `Observer` and `Observable` interfaces are weird. Even in a language without delegates/events, you'd still give these things concrete names or some message to pass in the function call. These make it seem as though there's only ever one (implied) event signaled between two objects.

...and that's about it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. A number of questions: 1- Why do you think it's a bad idea to have a singleton that stores all the notes and chords? 2- The way I designed it, is that the Melody takes care of when to play and stop notes, instead of the note taking care of it by itself (i.e. stopping itself after it's duration). Why do you think it would be better for the Note to do it itself, instead of the Melody managing all of this 'from above'? 3- Do you mean that I should create interfaces for the generators, and have the Model depends on them, instead of the concrete generators?

Comment: @prog - A singleton is an anti-pattern. It forces you to only ever have one of an object, and that's not a requirement here. I don't think Note should play itself (point 2). Instead of your model taking the actual `ProgressionGenerator` (For example), it may be better to take `IProgressionGenerator` to allow different algorithms when that need inevitably arises

Comment: I see. How can I tell when an object should depend on an interface and when it should depend on a concrete type? I understand the flexibility with depending on interfaces, but how can I sense when an object should depend on an interface and when it can depend on an actual class?

Comment: @prog - Some will say always use interfaces. Fewer will say always use real classes until you need the flexibility. Personally, I think that somewhere in the middle (though erring towards interfaces) is right. If you're **sure** that you won't ever need the flexibility, then just use the class. But remember that it's hard to predict the future, and it's always less work to have an interface you don't need than to break everything to put in an interface you need after the fact.

Comment: When someone says always use an interface - does that mean that classes should always have member attributes of an interface type rather than a class type? E.g., a `Human` class will always have attributes `ILeg`, `IArm`, `IHead`, instead of `Leg`, `Arm` and `Head`?

Comment: @prog - yes, that is pretty much what they mean. You wouldn't want to prevent yourself from having [dudes with chainsaws on their hands](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106308/) after all.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Last question: How does my design fit the SOLID principles? And how does it fit OO principles in general? Any advice on how to better integrate SOLID and OO principles into my designs in the future?

Comment: @prog - that is probably too long/complicated for me to answer here.

Comment: There is a notation where notes have not only letters but numbers. So C1 would be a very low bass note while A5 would be in the middle and D8 would be very high. I do not remember all the details but it would be worth looking up.

Comment: I also want to address the singleton issue -- notes are very lightweight objects, I would either use a factory (GC languages) or a [Flyweight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) (non-GC languages).

Comment: You mean that I should have a factory to produces the Notes, instead of a fixed collection of them stored in a singleton and accessed from there?